# How to make installation packages "trusted"?

Tags: software-center

I tried to install skype on ubuntu 13.04. It showed up in the software center fine, but when I tried to install skype, it said that it would require the the installation of untrusted packages. Is there any way to work past that?

Comment: Is there any way to make the sources authenticated so I can get skype with ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Skype is not open-source software, and software like that will always stay untrusted. If community can't see the code, help make it better, depending on few developers, it should stay untrusted!

If you still wish to use it, open Synaptic package manager, /Settings/Repositories
and in first tab you have software '**downloadable from the internet**', check `Software restricted by copyright and legal issues` and `Proprietary drivers for devices`, socond one you might not need for skype.